# Telerik grid pagination does not show other page numbers

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, telerik

I am using below code in my view and i am returning GridModel on ajax request.

I have checked GridModel values and Total property is 21 and Data property has 10 items. But Telerik grid does not show other pages. There is only "1" page number on pagination.

What is problem ?

```
@(Html.Telerik().Grid<SerialListItem>()
        .Name("Grid")
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(o => o.Id).Width(100).Hidden();
            columns.Bound(o => o.SerialNo).Width(200);
            columns.Bound(o => o.CreatedDate);
            columns.Bound(o => o.UsedDate);
            columns.Bound(o => o.Name);
            columns.Bound(o => o.Email);
        })
        .DataBinding(dataBinding => dataBinding.Ajax().Select("GetSerials", "Admin"))
        .Resizable(cfg=>cfg.Columns(true))
        .Pageable()
        .Sortable()
        .Filterable()
        .Sortable()
)
```

Edit:

I have realized a thing. I have checked ajax request via chrome developer tools. I saw that there is 10 item in data property and total property is 10. Huhhh

I have checked Total property in server side by debugging and it is 21 so how it can be 10 after serialized ??

Comment: Any idea or guess ? Everything looks ok in code ?

Answer (score 0):

Just change GridAction attribute to GridAction(EnableCustomBinding=true) and it works as it is expected.

But still couldn't understand why. Documentation does not point about it. Please check
 [Telerik pagination demo](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/razor/grid/paging)

```
    [GridAction(EnableCustomBinding=true)]
    public ActionResult GetSerials(GridCommand command)
    {

        GridModel model = service.GetSerials(command);

        return View(model);
    }
```

Comment: The documentation is here (check custom ajax binding): http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-mvc/telerik-ui-components-grid-data-binding-custom-binding.html